# As a common appbar widget how to change appbar color when page is scrolled Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, scroll, widget, appbar

Good morning friends, I'm trying to make the appbar transparent or white in scrollable
parts.
For me, this solution [An efficient way in Flutter to change appbar color when scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63706115/an-efficient-way-in-flutter-to-change-appbar-color-when-scrolled) works, but as the person said, I don't want to use setState continuously and do it in every separate component, so I'm trying to do what is mentioned in the comment. For this reason, I created a common appbar widget so that I can use it in other components. I made the CustomAppBar widget statefull, but I don't know where to add the scrollController. Therefore, I see errors. If anyone has time, can you help?
The code below is the widget where I call CustomAppBar.

```
  import ...
    
      const ExtractionBody({Key? key, required this.goal}) : super(key: key);
      final Objective goal;
    
      @override
      ExtractionBodyState createState() => ExtractionBodyState();
    }
    
    class ExtractionBodyState extends ConsumerState<ExtractionBody> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
          appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(100),
            child: CustomAppBar(
              icon: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(PhosphorIcons.xBold),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                  HomePage.routeName,
                  (route) => false,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: ExtractionRequestContent(
              goal: widget.goal, scrollController: _scrollController),
        );
      }
    }
```

Finally, this is my CustomAppBar code. Thank you very much in advance. and have a good weekend everyone

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatefulHookConsumerWidget {
  static String routeName = "/extraction_body";

  const CustomAppBar({Key? key, this.icon})
      : preferredSize = const Size.fromWidth(50),
        super(key: key);
  final Widget? icon;
  @override
  final Size preferredSize; // default is 56.0
  @override
  CustomAppBarState createState() => CustomAppBarState();

}

class CustomAppBarState extends ConsumerState<CustomAppBar> {
  bool isAppbarCollapsing = false;
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _initializeController() {
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.offset == 0.0 &&
          !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
        //Fully expanded situation
        if (!mounted) return;
        setState(() => isAppbarCollapsing = false);
      }
      if (_scrollController.offset >= 9.0 &&
          !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
        //Collapsing situation
        if (!mounted) return;
        setState(() => isAppbarCollapsing = true);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor:
          isAppbarCollapsing ? AppColors.monochromeWhite : Colors.transparent,
      title: Text(context.l10n.buttonCancel),
      titleSpacing: 4,
      leading: widget.icon,
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of define ScrollController in CustomAppBar, pass it in constructor like this:

```
 class CustomAppBar extends StatefulHookConsumerWidget {
  static String routeName = "/extraction_body";

  const CustomAppBar({Key? key, this.icon, required this.scrollController})
      : preferredSize = const Size.fromWidth(50),
        super(key: key);
  final Widget? icon;
  final ScrollController scrollController;
  @override
  final Size preferredSize; // default is 56.0
  @override
  CustomAppBarState createState() => CustomAppBarState();

}
```

and use it like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController(); //<---- define scrollController here
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(100),
              child: CustomAppbar(scrollController: scrollController)),
          body: ListView.builder(
            controller: scrollController,
            itemCount: 10,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.red,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
              );
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer Can I ask something? How did you get this scrollController: scrollController part in the another widget? I wrote what you say but here is giving error. :/


 preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(100),
              child: CustomAppbar(scrollController: scrollController)),
          body: ListView.builder(
            controller: scrollController,

Thanks!

Comment: If you issue is that its not recognize scrollController? I update my answer. check it out

Comment: Glad to hear that, if it helps you, please approve and up vote it, so other people could find it.